# Bluetooth UWP RequestAccessAsync() ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, uwp, bluetooth

I am building an app in Unity which uses Bluetooth to read from various sensors e.g. heart rate. I am trying to communicate with different Bluetooth devices at once. When I try to subscribe to more than 1 (sometimes 2 work) notification characteristics I get a "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object." exception at line "var accessStatus = await service.RequestAccessAsync();". Is there a way to prevent that asynchronous task from being disposed since I believe that this is the problem, or is there any other issue?

```
private async Task CommunicateWithDevice(CustomBluetoothDevice device) {
  #if WINDOWS_UWP
      if (device.bluetoothServices.Count == 0) {
        Debug.LogError("No services available. Did you forget to call GetDeviceServices?");
        return;
      }
    
      foreach(var bluetoothService in device.bluetoothServices) {
        var service = bluetoothService.Value.gattService;
    
        if ((bluetoothService.Key.Equals(GattGuids.POWER_SERVICE) || bluetoothService.Key.Equals(GattGuids.CSC_SERVICE)) && !userSelectedDeviceCategories.Contains(bluetoothService.Key)) //XX.Contains !bluetoothService.Key.Equals(userSelectedDeviceCategory
        {
          continue;
        }
    
        var accessStatus = await service.RequestAccessAsync();
        Debug.Log("service: " + service.Uuid + " | accessStatus: " + accessStatus);
        if (accessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed) {
          try {
            var characteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (characteristicsResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success) {
              foreach(var characteristic in characteristicsResult.Characteristics) {
                GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
    
                if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read)) {
                  SaveReadCharacteristic(device, characteristic);
                }
                if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write)) {
                  await WriteToCharacteristic(device, characteristic, true);
                }
                if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify)) {
                  await NotifyOnCharacteristic(device, characteristic);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
            Debug.Log("CommunicateWithDevice catch: " + e);
            await CommunicateWithDevice(device);
          }
        }
      }
  #endif
}
```

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.   at
> BluetoothController.CommunicateWithDevice (CustomBluetoothDevice
> device) [0x00165] in
> D:\GitHub\BleApp\Assets\Scripts\Bluetooth\BluetoothController.cs:413
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine]
> (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> BluetoothController.CommunicateWithDevice (CustomBluetoothDevice
> device) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> BluetoothController.CommunicateWithDevice (CustomBluetoothDevice
> device) [0x004e3] in
> D:\GitHub\BleApp\Assets\Scripts\Bluetooth\BluetoothController.cs:444
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext
> (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run
> () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.InvokeAction
> (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback
> (System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTask) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run
> (System.Threading.Tasks.Task ignored, System.Boolean
> canInlineContinuationTask) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean
> bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException (System.Object
> exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult].SetException
> (System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetException
> (System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> BluetoothController.NotifyOnCharacteristic (CustomBluetoothDevice
> device,
> Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattCharacteristic
> characteristic) [0x0013c] in
> D:\GitHub\BleApp\Assets\Scripts\Bluetooth\BluetoothController.cs:490
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext
> (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run
> () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0
> (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    at
> UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke ()
> [0x0000e] in
> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:153
> at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x00058] in
> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:83
> at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00015]
> in
> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Scripting\UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:107
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: So this exception happens when you are trying to subscribe to the second Bluetooth device? Or does it happen even when trying to subscribe to the first Bluetooth device?

Comment: yes it happens when I am trying to request access from the second or third device

Comment: What about running the method again instead of using a for-each loop when trying to connect to the second device? Will it succeed?

Comment: The method CommunicateWithDevice(CustomBluetoothDevice device){...} is called from a foreach loop for each Bluetooth device. The foreach loop in the CommunicateWithDevice(CustomBluetoothDevice device){...} method just handles/communicates with the different services from one Bluetooth device. Did this help clear thing up?

Comment: It's hard to say. So I think the first thing is to confirm if the normal process works for the second device when you've already subscribed to one.

Comment: Yes it even fails before trying to subscribe to the notifications, while requesting access.

Comment: Could you please try the official Bluetooth sample: [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE)? In scenario2, it could also subscribe to BLE devices. Will it give you the same exception?

Comment: I have a custom version of the BluetoothLE sample where I don't get that exception. So I assume that it has to do something with unity.